# Como ordenar uma string por fragmento inicial?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

Preciso ordenar uma *string* oriunda do `git tag -ln`.

```
2019.3.0        Primeira versão totamente integrada com gitlab-ci
2019.3.0-dev0   Aplicado correções sugeridas por py3kwarn
2019.3.0-dev1   refatorado o metodo test_merge_csv_files0 para operar gitlab-ci com validação de csv
2019.3.0-dev2   import faker corrigido
2019.3.0-dev3   FAIL: test_discover_url_0 (TestAtosWebSF) corrigida
2019.3.0-dev4   corrigido ERROR: Failure: Error (unsupported locale setting)
2019.3.0-dev5   corrigido AssertionError em test_discover_url_0
2019.3.1        2019.3.1-dev0 → 2019.3.1
2019.3.1-dev0   fatoração de metodo a ser implementado futuramente
2019.3.10       Correções em epigrafe com mesmo numero
2019.3.11       Correções em º/°
2019.3.12       Correções em 'Nº 1.420 A'
2019.3.13       Corrigido diversos erros de falso positivo na localização da epigrafe e no capabilities para windows
2019.3.14       ferramentas e relatórios para reconstrução do acervo
2019.3.2        Validação gitlab-ci completa
```

Desejado:

```
2019.3.13       Corrigido diversos erros de falso positivo na localização da epigrafe e no capabilities para windows
2019.3.12       Correções em 'Nº 1.420 A'
2019.3.11       Correções em º/°
2019.3.10       Correções em epigrafe com mesmo numero
2019.3.2        Validação gitlab-ci completa
2019.3.1        2019.3.1-dev0 → 2019.3.1
2019.3.1-dev0   fatoração de metodo a ser implementado futuramente
2019.3.0        Primeira versão totamente integrada com gitlab-ci
2019.3.0-dev5   corrigido AssertionError em test_discover_url_0
2019.3.0-dev4   corrigido ERROR: Failure: Error (unsupported locale setting)
2019.3.0-dev3   FAIL: test_discover_url_0 (TestAtosWebSF) corrigida
2019.3.0-dev2   import faker corrigido
2019.3.0-dev1   refatorado o metodo test_merge_csv_files0 para operar gitlab-ci com validação de csv
2019.3.0-dev0   Aplicado correções sugeridas por py3kwarn
```

Ou aceitável:

```
2019.3.14       ferramentas e relatórios para reconstrução do acervo
2019.3.13       Corrigido diversos erros de falso positivo na localização da epigrafe e no capabilities para windows
2019.3.12       Correções em 'Nº 1.420 A'
2019.3.11       Correções em º/°
2019.3.10       Correções em epigrafe com mesmo numero
2019.3.2        Validação gitlab-ci completa
2019.3.1-dev0   fatoração de metodo a ser implementado futuramente
2019.3.1        2019.3.1-dev0 → 2019.3.1
2019.3.0-dev5   corrigido AssertionError em test_discover_url_0
2019.3.0-dev4   corrigido ERROR: Failure: Error (unsupported locale setting)
2019.3.0-dev3   FAIL: test_discover_url_0 (TestAtosWebSF) corrigida
2019.3.0-dev2   import faker corrigido
2019.3.0-dev1   refatorado o metodo test_merge_csv_files0 para operar gitlab-ci com validação de csv
2019.3.0-dev0   Aplicado correções sugeridas por py3kwarn
2019.3.0        Primeira versão totamente integrada com gitlab-ci
```

Com este código obtive o resultado seguinte.

```
for i in sorted(lista.split(sep='\n'), reverse=True):
    print(i)
```

Obtido:

```
2019.3.2        Validação gitlab-ci completa
2019.3.13       Corrigido diversos erros de falso positivo na localização da epigrafe e no capabilities para windows
2019.3.12       Correções em 'Nº 1.420 A'
2019.3.11       Correções em º/°
2019.3.10       Correções em epigrafe com mesmo numero
2019.3.1-dev0   fatoração de metodo a ser implementado futuramente
2019.3.1        2019.3.1-dev0 → 2019.3.1
2019.3.0-dev5   corrigido AssertionError em test_discover_url_0
2019.3.0-dev4   corrigido ERROR: Failure: Error (unsupported locale setting)
2019.3.0-dev3   FAIL: test_discover_url_0 (TestAtosWebSF) corrigida
2019.3.0-dev2   import faker corrigido
2019.3.0-dev1   refatorado o metodo test_merge_csv_files0 para operar gitlab-ci com validação de csv
2019.3.0-dev0   Aplicado correções sugeridas por py3kwarn
2019.3.0        Primeira versão totamente integrada com gitlab-ci
```

Também tentei indexar a chave como inteiro, como abaixo, mas neste caso não é aceitável e gera uma exceção.

```
for i in sorted(lista.split(sep='\n'), reverse=True, key=int):
    print(i)
```

Como posso resolver este problema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Talvez esse código possa te ajudar. =D

Nele eu utilizei o parâmetro `key` da função `sorted` para passar uma função  que retornara o valor que será usado para a ordenação.

Nessa função eu vou utilizar expressões regulares, para separar a *data-review*(`2019.3.0-dev0`) e depois pegar separado `ano`,`mes`,`dia` e `review number`, após isso corrigir o `dia`/`mês` para 2 dígitos e adicionar um `review number` alto se não tiver.

```
 2019.3.0-dev4  =>  20190300.4
 2019.3.0-dev5  =>  20190300.5
 2019.3.1       =>  20190301.9999
 2019.3.1-dev0  =>  20190301.0
```

```py
import re

lista = """2019.3.0        Primeira versão totamente integrada com gitlab-ci
2019.3.0-dev0   Aplicado correções sugeridas por py3kwarn
2019.3.0-dev1   refatorado o metodo test_merge_csv_files0 para operar gitlab-ci com validação de csv
2019.3.0-dev2   import faker corrigido
2019.3.0-dev3   FAIL: test_discover_url_0 (TestAtosWebSF) corrigida
2019.3.0-dev4   corrigido ERROR: Failure: Error (unsupported locale setting)
2019.3.0-dev5   corrigido AssertionError em test_discover_url_0
2019.3.1        2019.3.1-dev0 → 2019.3.1
2019.3.1-dev0   fatoração de metodo a ser implementado futuramente
2019.3.10       Correções em epigrafe com mesmo numero
2019.3.11       Correções em º/°
2019.3.12       Correções em 'Nº 1.420 A'
2019.3.13       Corrigido diversos erros de falso positivo na localização da epigrafe e no capabilities para windows
2019.3.14       ferramentas e relatórios para reconstrução do acervo
2019.3.2        Validação gitlab-ci completa"""

pegar_data_extra = re.compile("\ {2,}")
pegar_ano_mes_dia = re.compile("(\d{4})\.(\d{1,2})\.(\d{1,2}).*")
pegar_extra = re.compile("-dev([^ ]+)")

def formatar_para_sort( x ):
    x = pegar_data_extra.split( x )[0]
    tmp = pegar_ano_mes_dia.search( x )
    extra = pegar_extra.search( x )
    ano = tmp.group(1)
    mes = tmp.group(2)
    dia = tmp.group(3)

    # pegar versão, se não tiver colocar uma alta 9999 
    extra = extra.group(1) if extra else "9999"

    # corrigir mes/dia para 2 digitos
    mes = "0"+mes if len(mes) < 2 else mes
    dia = "0"+dia if len(dia) < 2 else dia

    out = ano+mes+dia+"."+extra

    #print(x, " => ", out)

    return out

l = sorted(lista.split(sep='\n'), key=formatar_para_sort, reverse=True)

for i in l:
    print( i )
```

[Exemplo rodando no ideone](https://ideone.com/0wExOP)

Comment: sensacional tua sacada!!! :D

Answer (score 2):

O dado é ruim e aí vai ter que fazer algum tratamento nele para dar certo. O ideal seria que o dado viesse de forma mais organizada. Tem várias formas de fazer isto e não sei qual é a melhor sem saber o que pode ser feito, o que pode vir, o que é aceitável em todos os pontos, vou dar uma solução possível. Se tivesse mandando um código que mostrasse o que tentou funcionando, ou seja um [mcve], eu teria colocado um teste mostrando o resultado.

O problema é que um dos elementos pode ter 1 ou 2 dígitos numéricos e aí como é um texto 2 vem depois de 1 de acordo com a coluna que está comparando. Ou seja comparando "2 " com "11" o menor é "11", afinal a primeira coluna é 1 nela e 2 na outra. O ideal era o dado vir "02", aí não teria problema de comparação. Como não veio você deve colocar esse 0.

Se puder em algum caso ter 3 dígitos já complica mais e tem que tratar isso, se o elemento anterior que aí está tudo 3 puder ter o mesmo problema tem que tratar também, o mesmo para os `dev-x`.

Então crie uma função que normalize o dado do jeito que a classificação funcione e adote ela como chave da função `sorted()`, algo assim deve funcionar:

```
def normaliza(texto):
    return texto[:7] + (("0" + texto[7]) if (not texto[8].isnumeric()) else (texto[7:9])) + texto[9:]
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/String/Normalize.py).

Estou pegando o começo e fim do texto normal, o miolo é que muda. Se ele encontrar um dado não numérico onde deveria ter o segundo dígito numérico naquela posição então ele deve colocar um caractere `0` na frente daquele dígito encontrado ali, caso contrário ele deve pegar os dois caracteres normais porque já estão normalizados.